# Child element get 0 width when dynamically changing start/end properties

Tags: html, css, elixir, tailwind-css, phoenix-framework

I have a double range slider, similar to the one implemented [here](https://w3collective.com/double-range-slider-html-css-js/). Unlike that tutorial, I am using TailwindCSS and am writing the Elixir/Phoenix/LiveView code.

I was able to translate most of the things into my codebase, but I stumbled upon one problem:

When I move sliders, the "selected" range should also change following both sliders. (the dark blue part in the tutorial). The author changes the `left` and `right` values in CSS styles via javascript. Since I don't have that, here's my solution:

```
<div class="relative h-2 rounded-full bg-zinc-400">
  <span class={"absolute h-full #{start_end(@survey)} rounded-full bg-zinc-600"}></span>
</div>
```

The parent `div` is the outer range (the light blue in the tutorial), the child `span` is the selected range (the dark blue in the tutorial).

The `start_end(@survey)` function returns `"start-[40%] end-[70%]"`. The numbers change dynamically while the sliders are being dragged.

Here's the problem:

on initial page loading the selected range displays perfectly fine. But when I start dragging one of the sliders, it disappears and web inspector shows that the span has 0px width and 8px height.

If I drag the sliders back to initial position `"start-[40%] end-[70%]"`, it displays again. Drag away - it hides, until I reach exactly `"start-[25%] end-[70%]"`, then it displays again, then hides again until I reach `"start-[10%] end-[70%]"` or `"start-[0%] end-[70%]"`.
If I change the initial `end` value, then, while dragging, it will reappear on other `start` values (e.g. 30, 15, etc).

I have tried to use `start + width`, `left + width`, `left + right`, `inset-x- + width`. The behaviour remains the same.

Please advise me on what can be the problem here.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with [Tailwind's Dynamic Classnames](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names). "If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS." Whenever I run into this, I just throw the dynammic styles into a style tag on the element.

Comment: @Rico I tried that, and you're absolutely right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comment by @Rico, I changed the code to the following:

```
<div class="relative h-2 rounded-full bg-zinc-400">
  <span
    class="rounded-full bg-zinc-600"
    style={"position:absolute; height:100%; #{start_end(@survey)}"}
  >
  </span>
</div>
```

Where `start_end` now returns `"left:40%;right:30%;"`.